# iOS - Notification of when a call is taking place?

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications

Is it possible to be notified or detect when a GSM/CDMA call is taking place on an iOS handset?

I have an application that uses audio in the background and I want to be able to detect when a call is taking place so that my app can react accordingly so as not to intrude on the cellular call in anyway.

Essentially I want to be able to detect when a call is taking place so that if the user enters my application while on a call I can disable some functionality.

So I was wondering how I can detect that a cellular call is taking place on a device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of iOS 4, you can use the [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) class in the Core Telephony framework to register an event handler so your app gets notified when a call starts or ends. The CTCall it gives you has a `callState` property, which can be `CTCallStateDialing`, `CTCallStateIncoming`, `CTCallStateConnected`, or—when it ends—`CTCallStateDisconnected`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the phone number of an incoming call?

Comment: not working, do I need to update the plist also? like register for a background process ....

Comment: Not sure if this helps anyone but I just didn't want to animate a UIView if a call was taking place and this check worked perfect: if (callCenter.currentCalls == nil).....with callCenter being an instance of CTCallCenter.

Comment: Will it be approved by Apple Review team?

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 6, you should:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAudioInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:session
```

and then:

```
- (void)onAudioInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;
    NSUInteger type = [[info valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    if (type == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan) {
        // stop audio (or whatever)
    } else if (type == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded) {
        // restart audio (or whatever)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008241).

Comment: Thanks, I already have implemented that but it only appears to work if the user is using my app and then I get an incoming call, if my app is not in use, the user makes a call and then goes to my app during the call I want to disable some options at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreTelephony framework.But you must user some private api.And I have some demo code for this. https://github.com/edison0951/AppNotifyBySMSDemo. And the finally solution is MAP.this is the same with [SMS notifications in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494849/sms-notifications-in-ios6)