# iOS push notifications of other apps

Tags: ios, push-notification, notificationcenter

Is there a way of receiving all the push notifications of all apps?
So all notifications being displayed in the notification center?

If yes, is it also possible to perform an action when any push notification from any app is received?

Thanks

EDIT: It is not important if the app will be accepted by Apple.

Comment: Short answer: no, and it wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: why wouldnt it make sence at all?

Comment: If it would be possible, a "bad" app could get private data from other apps. Also, the user wants to decide which notifications to show, that's why he/she can do that in settings. An app like this would make that pointless.

Comment: The app is just for me so that wouldn't be a problem, do you know how to do it or just that it is possible?

Comment: I know that it isn't possible unless you are going to use jailbreak.

Comment: And how would it work using a jailbreak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notifications are dispatched to the app that registered to receive them.

You cannot access all notifications, so the short answer would be **no**.

Comment: But there is an app that does this: GShock+ by casio (gshock.com/watches/Classic/GB6900AA-1)! (Quote: "Incoming Notfications")

Comment: That app is registering for incoming calls, a thing you can do using the `CTCallCenter` class (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530934/ios-notification-of-when-a-call-is-taking-place).

Comment: Concerning the emails I suspect that you need to enter your email account info in the app itself, in order to get notified.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't there a way to get the notifications?

Comment: Actually, what I suspect the watch is doing is linking with your iPhone over BlueTooth. The iPhone includes built-in support for telling BlueTooth devices about incoming calls, email and Messages.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notifyr-receive-ios-notifications/id873639935?l=nl&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: @jamapag, that uses ANCS, which is made for Bluetooth accessories. Only the external accessory will be notified, so it's still impossible for an app to directly access the notification center. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW7

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Notifications are considered by Apple to be private.

There is no (public) way to do this that would still get your app accepted into the App Store.

Comment: I dont want it to get accepted in the AppStore, but there is an App in the AppStore doing this: GShock by casio(http://www.gshock.com/watches/Classic/GB6900AA-1)!

Comment: @user1710004 Actually, what I suspect the watch is doing is linking with your iPhone over Bluetooth. The iPhone includes built-in support for telling Bluetooth devices about incoming calls, email and Messages.