# How to detect notification from other iOS app in our app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way where we can detect App 1’s notification when App2 is running in  foreground or background.

Can we detect if App 1’s notification is Clicked or launched in App2 ?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS push notifications of other apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260037/ios-push-notifications-of-other-apps)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can achieve by using [Interactive notification](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/).

You can track that notification is clicked or not.

Implement `Interactive notification` in App1 and When you tap any action of it sent another push notification to App2 to notify.

This is one solution you can achieve by different technique also.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Push Notifications are only dispatched to the app that registered for them. You had to generate certificates related to the app in order to receive APN so it is normal that another app cannot access those notifications.